# Why is this JS synthax error given?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var message = "Geachte " + $("#person_name").val() + ",<br/><br/> U heeft aangegeven diensten van OZMO cloud communications op te willen zeggen. Graag willen wij u verzoeken een “reply” op deze mail te sturen met daarin aangegeven dat u akkoord gaat met deze opzegging en eventuele kosten.<br/><br/>De opdrachtgever is <?= $row['company_name'] ?> gevestigd aan de <?= $row['company_address'] ?> te <?= $row['company_city'] ?>. Namens de opdrachtgever treedt "+ $("#person_name").val() +" op als bevoegd vertegenwoordiger.<br/><br/>Te beeindigen OZMO cloud communication BV diensten:<br/><table><tr><td>Type dienst</td><td>Datum beëindiging</td><td>Kosten beëindiging</td></tr>";
```

Now I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This is the error in my console:
[image]

What I'm doing wrong?
I always used it this way and worked.

Comment: Try to replace the quotes in `“reply”` or remove them at all...

Comment: maybe `<?= $row['company_name'] ?>` returns invalid chars like new lines?

Comment: The code you've posted does not show this symptom. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: The JS in itself is fine. The problem is likely being caused by one of your PHP `echo` statements, such as `<?= $row['company_name'] ?>` containing a quote which is breaking the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add a php variable. In this Case you should use "echo" and not "="

```
var message = "Geachte " + $("#person_name").val() + ",<br/><br/> U heeft aangegeven diensten van OZMO cloud communications op te willen zeggen. Graag willen wij u verzoeken een “reply” op deze mail te sturen met daarin aangegeven dat u akkoord gaat met deze opzegging en eventuele kosten.<br/><br/>De opdrachtgever is <?echo $row['company_name']; ?> gevestigd aan de <? echo $row['company_address']; ?> te <? echo $row['company_city']; ?>. Namens de opdrachtgever treedt "+ $("#person_name").val() +" op als bevoegd vertegenwoordiger.<br/><br/>Te beeindigen OZMO cloud communication BV diensten:<br/><table><tr><td>Type dienst</td><td>Datum beëindiging</td><td>Kosten beëindiging</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Yes It works but I don't know why???

Comment: Why dislike my answer. Its works because you need the return of the data. so you use echo.

Comment: @NicoZimmer "_Why dislike my answer._" Because you didn't add that information. Q&A's on Stack Overflow are to serve/educate the community as a whole, not just the OP. This code is 698 characters. You don't expect everybody to compare this code character by character to spot the difference do you?